# How to see each date on each point, using mpldatacursor points_labels? And pprint_val function deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1

Tags: date, datetime, matplotlib, label, display

I am calling for help, because something wrent wrong on my python script... I want to display dates when clicking on my points, but the result is that the whole list of dates is printed on each point...

```
#lon_valid and lat_valid are both a list of coordinates
#times_to_dates is a list of datetimes objects
#both these lists are long (about 300k objects)
strin=[str(w) for w in times_to_dates]

if len(lon_valid)==len(lat_valid):
        fig, ax=plt.subplots()
        fig.suptitle("Latitude vs longitude, on mooring "+str(my_file.platform_name)+" ("+str(my_file.platform_code)+")")
        ax.set_xlabel("longitude (°)")
        ax.set_ylabel("latitude (°)")
        plt.xticks(fontsize=7)
        ax.scatter(lon_valid,lat_valid,)
        datacursor(axes=ax, point_labels=strin)
        plt.show()
else: print("Error: Number of datas between VHM0 and TIME different")
```

Here is a screenshot, to make myself clearer: 
[screenshot_too_many_dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUteM.jpg)

Could you someone explain me where is the problem? It seems to be linked to the "point_labels" variable, but know how to solve it. I tried with just some dots, and a small list, everything is alright over here...

```
labels = [str(datetime(2004,12,4)), str(datetime(2005,5,4)), 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
x = [0, 0.05, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# All points on this figure will point labels.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, x, 'ro')
ax.margins(0.1)
datacursor(axes=ax, point_labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

Finally, I would also like to know if this message is a big problem or not... Will one be able to use mpldatacursor in the future the same way than before, or will it be necessary changing the scripts?

```
/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpldatacursor/datacursor.py:413: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The pprint_val function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
```

Thanks a lot for your help ! :)

Comment: Did you make sure you upgraded mpldatacursor?

Comment: I  used pip install mpldatacursor, and also pip install matplotlib, and still have the same message...

Comment: The github repo of mpldatacursor has a bunch of commits for matplotlib 3.1.  So either upgrade your moldatacursors using the GitHub version or downgrade your matplotlib.